# Using EmojiOne With React

Tags: reactjs, emojione

I've been trying to use EmojiOne with React.js with the standard .toImage (see docs http:// git.emojione.com/demos/latest/jstoimage.html). Here is what my code looks like, more or less

```
//react imports
import emoji from 'emojione';
//class component etc. render
return(
//other things from component
    {emoji.toImage(':smile:')}
)
```

Which gives me

[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aemfu.png)

Here's what it looks like in inspect element:

[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZvkf.png)

So from what I can tell, the emojione library is putting the image code into React as text, rather than as an element. Any idea why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React is escaping the output from EmojiOne to avoid cross-site scripting attacks. You could (but probably shouldn't...) use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to inject the output from EmojiOne as "actual" HTML.

Someone has already written a React EmojiOne wrapper that may be useful: https://github.com/pladaria/react-emojione

For more info on `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` and why it should be avoided, take a look at: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html

Comment: Thanks! react-emojione looks like it uses the old version of emojione. But I think I might have something figured out, I'll post it in a minute

Comment: @EliYazdi I think u forgot to post what u figured out. Please post it as I am facing the same issue

Comment: @EliYazdi did you get a working solution, I'm facing the same issue.